# How to skip a ggplot2 code if it fails/errors - Need help writing extensible, fault-tolerant code

Tags: r, ggplot2

Sample Data:

```
dat <- structure(list(n_speed = c(7, 6, 5, 4, 7, 6, 4, 9), id = c("subj_1", 
"subj_1", "subj_1", "subj_1", "subj_2", "subj_2", "subj_2", "subj_2"
), timepoint = c("t1", "t1", "t2", "t2", "t1", "t1", "t2", "t2"
), direction = c("long", "lat", "long", "lat", "long", "lat", 
"long", "lat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

speed_measures <- structure(list(n_speed = c(7, 6, 5, 4, 7, 6, 4, 9), id = c("subj_1", 
"subj_1", "subj_1", "subj_1", "subj_2", "subj_2", "subj_2", "subj_2"
), timepoint = c("t1", "t1", "t2", "t2", "t1", "t1", "t2", "t2"
), direction = c("long", "lat", "long", "lat", "long", "lat", 
"long", "lat")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

dat_combined <- speed_measures |> left_join(dat)
```

I have code that looks like this:

```
ggplot(data = dat_combined, aes(x = n_speed)) +
     geom_histogram() +
     facet_wrap(~direction)
```

and am getting the following error:

```
Error in `combine_vars()`:
! Faceting variables must have at least one value
Backtrace:
 1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
 2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
 4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
 5. layout$setup(data, plot$data, plot$plot_env)
 6. ggplot2 (local) setup(..., self = self)
 7. self$facet$compute_layout(data, self$facet_params)
 8. ggplot2 (local) compute_layout(..., self = self)
 9. ggplot2::combine_vars(data, params$plot_env, vars, drop = params$drop)
```

This is because the data I'm currently running does not contain the "factor" that facet_wrap is looking for. I am trying to make this code extensible so that I can run data where subjects may or may not have that "factor" available, and don't want to rewrite a seperate pipeline for this situation.

I have attempted and failed with:

```
try(ggplot(data = dat_combined, aes(x = n_speed)) +
     geom_histogram() +
     facet_wrap(~direction))
```

Edit: Final code used after all the input:

```
if(is.na(dat_combined$n_speed[1])) { 
    print("No Data")
} else {
  ggplot(data = dat_combined, aes(x = n_speed)) +
          geom_histogram() +
          facet_wrap(~direction)
}
```

Comment: Better may be to create a function and derive the names from the data

Comment: Rather than attempting to run code that might not work and then trying to recover from an error, maybe check first? `p = ggplot(data = dat_combined, aes(x = dv)) +
  geom_histogram()` then `if("region" in names(dat_combined)) p = p + facet_wrap(~region)`.

Comment: @GregorThomas I keep getting caught up on: Error: unexpected 'in' in "if("region" in" for if("region" in names(dat_combined))

Comment: Use `%in%` to specify , rather than `in`.

Comment: I've updated my question with the final answer

Comment: If you have an answer, you should post it as an answer not make it part of the question! Then you can "accept" the answer which will indicate your question is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because "Factor" DOES exist in the DF but is empty, we cannot use the "if("region" in names(dat_combined))" method.

Instead, we can make sure that the column has no data by checking the first row. This could be a bit more elegant by checking that the entire column in empty, but for the structure I'm working with that's not necessary.

Final Answer:

```
if(is.na(dat_combined$n_speed[1])) { 
    print("No Data")
} else {
  ggplot(data = dat_combined, aes(x = n_speed)) +
          geom_histogram() +
          facet_wrap(~direction)
}
```

Comment: Consider `if (all(is.na(dat_combined$n_speed[1])))...`.